# What is a word that means to bind a connotation to a word in literature?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is a word that means to bind a connotation to a word in literature? Generally how I am trying to use it: Shakespeare binds an ironic meaning to the word fair blabla so every time somebody says fair, it turns out to be foul blabla... ¶ After the initial [blank] (of the ironic usage of fair)... succeeding uses of the "fair" show this...

If there is no such specific word, how can I say this?

Comment: Something like _reversal_, _reworking_, or _redefinition_?

Comment: Well he did not redefine the meaning of the word, but whenever the word is used, the reader knows that it actually means the opposite.

Comment: Perhaps *[co-opt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-opt)*, in its sense "To absorb or assimilate into an established group"; eg, "He co-opts the word *fair* to mean *foul*".

Comment: @jwpat7: Very nice. +1

Comment: "Binds" is a good word for this. Consider also "Associates", but IMO "binds" is actually the best word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually what you're describing is the definition of *connotation*.

- *From Dictionary.com:* the associated or secondary meaning of a word or expression in addition to its explicit or primary meaning: A possible connotation of “home” is “a place of warmth, comfort, and affection.”
- A word's *denotation* is its reference to the things it designates, its direct, explicit meaning; a word's *connotation* is things or attributes that the word brings to mind, any idea or notion suggested or associated with the word

So your example sentence could say:

Shakespeare gives the word *fair* a new and opposite connotation blabla so everytime somebody says *fair*, it turns out to be *foul*  blabla... After imposing this new connotation on the word *fair*... succeeding uses of *fair* show this...

Granted, the connotation of the word *fair* in the context of Shakespeare's play may not be the same as in the real world, but within the context of the play, Shakespeare is giving *fair* a new connotation.

Comment: I interpreted OP's question to be, "what do we call the dissemination of the new connotation."  So in your answer you are suggesting *to impose* a connotation.

Comment: @Jim - Yes, that actually answers the OP's question. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I guess you can't argue with the OP, but his question actually asks 'how do you do something *with* a connotation' which is *not* as your answer says, "the definition *of* connotation." But whatever- he seems to be happy.